# Segfault in Identical Loops and Arrays

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dynamic-arrays

So, I declare two 2D float arrays exactly the same way.

```
float** a1 = new float*[chunk_size];
for (i = 0; i < chunk_size; ++i) {
    a1[i] = new float[chunk_size];
}

float** a2 = new float*[chunk_size];
for (i = 0; i < chunk_size; ++i) {
    a2[i] = new float[chunk_size];
}
```

And then proceed to access the first one, then the second...

```
for (i = 0; i < chunk_size; ++i) {
    for (j = n = m = d = 0; j < chunk_size; j = m) {
        do {
            std::cout << "i: " << i << " m: " << m << std::endl;
            d = a1[i][m]; <-----------NO-SEGFAULT
            ++m;
        } while (d != 0 && m < chunk_size);
        delta = (d - a1[i][j]) / m;
        n = j + 1;
        while (n < j + m) {
            a1[i][n] = a1[i][n - 1] + delta;
            ++n;
        }
    }
}
```

And on the second loop set, I get a segfault on the first iteration.

```
for (j = 0; j < chunk_size; ++j) {
    for (i = n = m = d = 0; i < chunk_size; i = m) {
        do {
            std::cout << "m: " << m << " j: " << j << std::endl;
            d = a2[m][j]; <--------------SEGFAULT
            ++m;
        } while (d != 0 && m < chunk_size);
        delta = (d - a2[i][j]) / m;
        n = i + 1;
        while (n < i + m) {
            a2[n][j] = a2[n - 1][j] + delta;
            ++n;
        }
    }
}
```

Unless I'm missing something, or not sharing something else of importance I don't see what could be causing this in one and not the other.

For reference, i, j, n, m, and chunk_size are of type `size_t` while delta and d are of type `float`.

Edit: console output

```
 i: 255 m: 248
 i: 255 m: 249
 i: 255 m: 250
 i: 255 m: 251
 i: 255 m: 252
 i: 255 m: 253
 i: 255 m: 254
 i: 255 m: 255
 m: 0 j: 0
 Segmentation fault
```

The Valgrind Ouput

```
i: 255 m: 250
i: 255 m: 251
i: 255 m: 252
i: 255 m: 253
i: 255 m: 254
i: 255 m: 255
m: 0 j: 0
==3518== Use of uninitialised value of size 8    ==3518==    at 0x403240: WSUMap::blockTypeIDAt(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) const (WSUMap.h:196)
==3518==    by 0x402B54: WSUMap::WSUMap() (WSUMap.h:110)
==3518==    by 0x4017CB: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)     (main.cpp:8)
==3518==    by 0x4017E0: _GLOBAL__sub_I_map (main.cpp:20)
==3518==    by 0x403DFC: __libc_csu_init (in /home/will/Dev/a.out)
==3518==    by 0x5A2AE3F: (below main) (libc-start.c:203)
==3518== 
==3518== Invalid read of size 4
==3518==    at 0x403240: WSUMap::blockTypeIDAt(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) const (WSUMap.h:196)
==3518==    by 0x402B54: WSUMap::WSUMap() (WSUMap.h:110)
==3518==    by 0x4017CB: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)     (main.cpp:8)
==3518==    by 0x4017E0: _GLOBAL__sub_I_map (main.cpp:20)
==3518==    by 0x403DFC: __libc_csu_init (in /home/will/Dev/a.out)
==3518==    by 0x5A2AE3F: (below main) (libc-start.c:203)
==3518==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3518== 
==3518== 
==3518== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3518==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==3518==    at 0x403240: WSUMap::blockTypeIDAt(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) const (WSUMap.h:196)
==3518==    by 0x402B54: WSUMap::WSUMap() (WSUMap.h:110)
==3518==    by 0x4017CB: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)     (main.cpp:8)
==3518==    by 0x4017E0: _GLOBAL__sub_I_map (main.cpp:20)
==3518==    by 0x403DFC: __libc_csu_init (in /home/will/Dev/a.out)
==3518==    by 0x5A2AE3F: (below main) (libc-start.c:203)
==3518==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3518==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3518==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3518==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3518==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3518== 
==3518== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3518==     in use at exit: 3,225,736 bytes in 1,803 blocks
==3518==   total heap usage: 1,816 allocs, 13 frees, 3,279,401 bytes allocated
==3518== 
==3518== 122,880 bytes in 120 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 9 of 13
==3518==    at 0x4C28147: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:348)
==3518==    by 0x402E7B: WSUMap::blockTypeIDAt(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) const (WSUMap.h:162)
==3518==    by 0x402B54: WSUMap::WSUMap() (WSUMap.h:110)
==3518==    by 0x4017CB: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)     (main.cpp:8)
==3518==    by 0x4017E0: _GLOBAL__sub_I_map (main.cpp:20)
==3518==    by 0x403DFC: __libc_csu_init (in /home/will/Dev/a.out)
==3518==    by 0x5A2AE3F: (below main) (libc-start.c:203)
==3518== 
==3518== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3518==    definitely lost: 122,880 bytes in 120 blocks
==3518==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3518==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3518==    still reachable: 3,102,856 bytes in 1,683 blocks
==3518==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3518== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==3518== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==3518== 
==3518== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3518== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==3518== ERROR SUMMARY: 1144833 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
Segmentation fault
```

Here are the variables...

```
size_t i, j, n, m, chunk_size, pixel_size, scale;
i = j = n = m = 0;
chunk_size = 256;
pixel_size = 4;
scale = chunk_size / pixel_size;
float delta, d;
```

And here is the array declaration...

```
for (i = 0; i < pixel_size; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < pixel_size; ++j) {
        (i == 0) ? n = i : n = (i * scale) - 1;
        (j == 0) ? m = j : m = (j * scale) - 1;
        a1[n][m] = pixels[i][j];
        a2[n][m] = pixels[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you initializing those arrays with anything? If not you have undefined behavior when you attempt to read from them.

Comment: This is where I'm initializing them. Other than the 16 points (i, m) and (m, j) should all be the value when d is assigned.

Comment: @Dave  I don't see any initialization in your code wrt those 2d arrays.

Comment: @Dave Why not print out the values of those indices before you use them?  Wouldn't that simply answer your question?  In any event, unless you post real initialization code, all this is moot.  It is undefined behavior to assign from an uninitialized floating point variable, regardless of whether you're in bounds or not of your arrays.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what do you mean when you say "real initialization code", going through and setting them all to 0? Is the declaration not an initialization?

Comment: @Dave.  No it is not initialization.  All you did was allocate memory.  You need to set those values to something valid.  Those values in the arrays could be NAN's as far as we know, and you're attempting to assign a NAN to `d` (for example), causing a fault.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie When [i][m] is accessed at the beginning of those do...whiles they are set. They're 16 values in place that are in the [256][256] array.  And that doesn't explain why it didn't happen in the first loop, this is what I find the most perplexing thing here.

Comment: @Dave I think it's time you posted a full example that demonstrates the error.  There are too many missing pieces in the code you posted -- another example is that we have no idea what those variables "i", "j", etc are declared, since you're mixing float operations with int variables.  You say that those values are set -- I'm a skeptic -- exactly *how* are those items set?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = n = m = d = 0; i < chunk_size; i = m) {
    do {
        std::cout << "m: " << m << " j: " << j << std::endl;
        d = a2[m][j]; <--------------SEGFAULT
        ++m;
    } while (d != 0 && m < chunk_size);
```

Since you are using `do ... while()` statement, `m < chunk_size` is checked only after the first run of `do while` loop. Thus, in the 2nd run of inner `for`, the first run of the `do ... while` loop access out of array boundary.

You could either change it into `while(d != 0 && m < chunk_size) { ... }` or rewrite the logic to make sure you don't access `a2[m][j]` when `m >= chunk_size || j >= chunk_size`.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, here is the output

Comment: Use debugger to see what values those variables are when it's crashing.

Comment: I don't think that's the case here's the output and it segfaults a (0, 0) in the second loop-set. If it were getting above 255 this would cause that right?
i: 255 m: 248
i: 255 m: 249
i: 255 m: 250
i: 255 m: 251
i: 255 m: 252
i: 255 m: 253
i: 255 m: 254
i: 255 m: 255
m: 0 j: 0
Segmentation fault
will@debian:~/Dev$

Comment: The print statement puts (m, i) at (0, 0), the beginning of the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
while (n < j + m) {
```

`j+m` can easily become greater than chunk size. This would happen if you ever went around your for first loop loop when `m` was greater than `chunk_size /2`. This would lead to writing outside the bounds of your array and causing undefined behavior.

Comment: If that were the case, it would have occurred during the first loop. Since the debug-print statement stops at the beginning of the second loop and GDB and Valgrind all point me to the line marked above I'm pretty sure it's something to do with that.

Comment: @Dave Please attach valgrind output, especially the beginning of error messages instead of the last ones.

Comment: Writing outside the bounds of an array does not stop your program. It just trashes other data leading to potential problems later on. If you have run valgrind on your program you should say so in your question, possibly including the output from valgrind.

Comment: @TheDark standby, I'll attach is now.

Comment: You could also verify if `n` is becoming too big by putting out a trace write, either inside the `n` loop (which would be a lot) or even just test if `j + m >= chunk_size` before the loop and write out a trace in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If `chunk_size` is 256, then you are going out of bounds here:

```
       while (n < j + m) {
            a1[i][n] = a1[i][n - 1] + delta;
```

The value of `n` becomes 256, which is out of bounds.

Here is an example:  http://ideone.com/fAUA8j

Whenever `n` becomes 256, `"You're dead"` is printed.